# List problem - content aligned vertically but list aligned horizontally?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-tables

I have a list to which I've applied diplay:table-cell and vertical-align:middle styles to display the list items' contents centered vertically. Trouble is, the list itself then displays horizontally!

So I have the correct alignment on the individual items' content, but the wrong alignment on the items themselves.

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: list goes horizontal!]

What I'm looking for is the same thing, but the items on top of one another. Each item has a set width and height (100px) with standard margins and padding.

Here's my CSS and HTML:

```
ul#affiliations-list {
list-style: none;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 0 12px;
display: table;
width: 96px
}
ul#affiliations-list li{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 94px;
height: 94px;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #020336;
margin-bottom: 10px;
display:table-cell; 
vertical-align:middle;
position: relative
```

}

```
<ul id="affiliations-list">
            <li><img src="be39fb67466b1a11b4989713b51a268c.jpg" width="94" height="33" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="297b46e52846790f9bdb71bb0c54158f.png" width="94" height="29" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="d20e8a119dd54a7c73d058cd333dbd71.jpg" width="93" height="94" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="beb10861fed07a849e36d98922304751.gif" width="94" height="68" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Can you supply some html & css code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><div>correctly aligned</div></li>
    <li><div>correctly aligned</div></li>
    ...
</ul>

<style>
    div { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
</style>
```

Leave the `<li>` at their default styling, so you'll get them in "column" form, and then the div takes care of the alignment of the li's content.

Comment: That worked when I added display: table to the `<li>` tags! Thanks :)

Comment: By setting `display:table` on `li` `vertical-align:middle` will not work. So this is not a solution. And 1 more suggestion `display:table` & `display:table-cell` do not work in IE browsers less then IE 8. See the reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: I also added `line-height:0` to the `<div>` to make the vertical alignment properly in the middle, as it was slightly off without it.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm looking for is the same thing, but the items on top of one
>   another. Each item has a set width and height (100px) with standard
>   margins and padding.

YOu mean to align them vertically, If so add a break please. :-(
If you want them overlapped, layers seem to be the only way to go